# If $B$ is positive definite, then $(g^TBg) (g^TB^{-1}g) \ge (g^Tg)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove something in Optimization, and it comes down to proving the inequality
$$(g^TBg) (g^TB^{-1}g) \ge (g^Tg)^2$$
where $B$ is positive definite and $g$ is any vector.

I am able to prove it under the additional hypothesis that $B$ is symmetric. However, there are two things I don't like about my proof:

$1)$ It needs the extra hypothesis that $B$ is symmetric.

$2)$ I had to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with a non-standard inned product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I would prefer a proof which uses the version for the dot product.

Is it possible to write a proof with these things in mind?

**My Proof:** Consider the inner product $(u, v) = u^TBv$ and let $u = g$, $v = B^{-1}g$. By the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality,
$$(g^TBg) (g^TB^{-T}BB^{-1}g) \ge (g^TBB^{-1}g)^2$$

$$(g^TBg) (g^TB^{-1}g) \ge (g^Tg)^2$$

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that the statement still holds when $B$ is not symmetric? I suspect that this generalization is not true.

Comment: Doesn't positive definite include symmetric as one of the requirements in its definition?

Comment: @Divide1918 In some literature, a matrix with real entries is called positive semidefinite whenever we have $x^TAx \geq 0$ for all $x$, i.e. whenever the matrix $A + A^T$ is "symmetric and positive definite".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The only reason I think it might be true for non-symmetric matrices is that  in the theorem I'm trying to prove, the symmetry of $B$ is not stated as a hypothesis. And this is one of those books which makes a distinction between "p.d." and symmetric and "p.d.". However, in the context, $B$ is supposed to be an approximation to a Hessian, so it could very well be that the symmetry of $B$ is implied.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm very curious, could you please explain why your intuition says that this result is false for non-symmetric $B$? I would like to improve my intuition as well.

Comment: @Blue I don't have a compelling argument, unfortunately. It just comes down to the fact that $(g^TBg) (g^TB^{-1}g) \ge (g^Tg)^2$ looks a lot like Cauchy Schwarz, which requires an inner product and hence the symmetry of $B$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh okay thanks!

Comment: @Blue Another point: we can rewrite the inequality as 
$$
\frac{g^TBg}{g^Tg} \geq \frac{g^Tg}{g^TB^{-1}g}.
$$
Replacing $B$ with its symmetric part $\frac 12 (B + B^T)$ gives us the same left hand side, but a different right hand side.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Hmm but why would this suggest that the inequality is not true for non-symmetric matrices?

Comment: @Blue Because as I suspected (and now confirmed on pencil and paper), the right hand side can be made arbitrarily large. I'll write up an answer that gives a counterexample soon

Comment: @Blue on the matter of staying with standard inner products: you can do so if you use the fact that a symmetric positive definite $B$ has a symmetric positive definite square root.

Comment: @Blue Update: I had made a mistake in my scratch work (inequality was backwards), and now I think you might be right after all.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh I see how to solve it with the standard inner product now; $u = B^{1/2}g, v = B^{-1/2}g.$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If I was right, it was only by accident of course. If you feel like it, I would be very happy even with a wrong answer; I would be interested to see any of your work, since I have very little experience with matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement fails if $B$ is not necessarily symmetric. As a counterexample, consider the following:
$$
I = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}, \quad J = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}, \quad B = B(t) = I + tJ \ \ t >0.
$$
We find that $B^{-1} = \frac 1{1 + t^2}(I - tJ)$, from which it follows that
$$
g^TBg = g^Tg, \quad g^TB^{-1}g = \frac 1{1 + t^2}g^Tg.
$$
With that, the inequality becomes $\frac 1{1 + t^2}(g^Tg)^2 \geq (g^Tg)^2$, which clearly fails for all $t > 0$.

---

Regarding the Cauchy Schwarz inequality proof: as mentioned in the comments, it suffices to note that
$$
\|B^{1/2}g\|^2 \cdot \|B^{-1/2}g\|^2 \leq [(B^{-1/2}g)^T(B^{1/2}g)]^2,
$$
where $B$ is taken to be the unique symmetric positive definite square root of $B$.