# $|a^Tb| \leq \|a\|_{M} \|b\|_{M^{-1}}$ where $M$ is positive definite matrix and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: matrices, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

Is the following inequality true? If so what is it called?

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be a positive definite matrix and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Then

\begin{equation}
|a^Tb| \leq \|a\|_{M} \|b\|_{M^{-1}}
\end{equation}

where $\|a\|_{M} = \sqrt{a^T Ma}$

It does look like Holder inequality but I am not sure if Holder holds for matrix induced norm as well

Comment: Have you seen it somewhere? How have you tried to prove it?

Comment: supposing $M$ is symmetric (as it should be for a symmetric bilinear form) this is just Cauchy Schwarz applied to $M^\frac{1}{2}\mathbf a$ and $M^\frac{-1}{2}\mathbf b$

Comment: I am sure that an old duplicate of this question had been bumped up to the front page earlier today.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3705892/81360) is a similar question.